# Why don't we search for lines in the XY space? Why in Hough Space?

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

We know that Hough Transform works in Hough Space which is actually an alternate universe of [2D XY space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space) (like Spatial vs Frequency domain representation of Images).

But, What is the **fundamental** advantage of using Hough Space?

Why don't we search for lines in the XY space?

Comment: XY space as in the image space? Finding lines is hard. The Hough transform transforms this problem into a peak finding problem, which is much easier.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, hmm.

Comment: The problem with vertical lines comes into play when parametrizing lines as offset + slope, as in Hough’s patent. He processed each image twice, with a 90 degree rotation in between, to circumvent this problem. The modern distance + angle parametrization was introduced by others as a better solution to that problem.

Comment: BTW: you should look into https://dsp.stackexchange.com for this type of question, you will be received better there, I think (though it’s a much smaller community than SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got the answer.

It is because, in XY space, it is problematic to represent vertical lines. Because, vertical lines have infinite slope.

According to **@ChrisLuengo**,

> Finding lines is hard. The Hough transform transforms this problem into a peak finding problem, which is much easier.

That is also a valid point.